# Does Django automatically generate indexes for foreign keys columns?

Tags: django-models

Does Django automatically generate indexes for foreign keys, or does it just depend on the underlying DB policy ?

Comment: depend on `db_index` parameter in ForeignKey, which by default is True.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Django automatically creates an index for all `models.ForeignKey` columns.

From [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> A database index is automatically created on the `ForeignKey`. You can disable this by setting `db_index` to `False`. You may want to avoid the overhead of an index if you are creating a foreign key for consistency rather than joins, or if you will be creating an alternative index like a partial or multiple column index.

Comment: I couldn't find any reference on this fact. Any reference to this ?

Comment: Run `./manage.py sql appname` and you'll see the SQL statements for the index creation. They come just after the SQL for the creation of the last table needed.

Comment: @LukeSneeringer, I'm not sure if the command you give used to show indices, but it no longer does. Instead, run `./manage.py sqlindexes appname` for the indices by themselves.

Comment: It is also possible to disable creation of an index on a ForeignKey: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/13730

Comment: @JesseBeder: that `./manage.py sqlindexes appname` doesn't work any longer in recent Django versions.

Comment: Link to source is broken, you might want to update it to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey

Comment: `manage.py sqlindexes` was removed in django 1.9 as shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/. In SQL, you can use `SHOW INDEX FROM yourtable;`, ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table

Comment: Does Django also create indexes for the primary key / Autofield?

Answer (score 2):

In interest of visibility and the discussion going on in the comments of the accepted answer, adding it here.

1. Yes, django automatically adds index for FK relationships.
2. You can disable this by passing db_index=False like

```py
models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=False)
```

3. This behavior depends on attached database -- (postgres/my-sql/oracle variants can have different SQL commands that are executed by django. MySQL creates such indexes automatically so django won't do that.)
4. To verify what command is running for you: run

```
 ./manage.py sqlmigrate <app-name> <migration-number>

like

 ./manage.py sqlmigrate posts 0005
```