# Trying to import SQL file in a xampp server returns error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I have done a ER diagram in Mysql Workbench, and I am trying load in my server with phpMyAdmin, but it returns me the next error:

```
Error
SQL Query:

-- ----------------------------------------------------- -- Table `BDA`.`UG` -- ----------------------------------------------------- CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`UG` ( `numero_ug` INT NOT NULL, `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `segunda_firma_autorizada` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL, `fecha_creacion` DATE NOT NULL, `nombre_depto` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL, `dni` INT NOT NULL, `anho_contable` INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`numero_ug`), INDEX `nombre_depto_idx` (`nombre_depto` ASC), INDEX `dni_idx` (`dni` ASC), INDEX `anho_contable_idx` (`anho_contable` ASC), CONSTRAINT `nombre_depto` FOREIGN KEY (`nombre_depto`) REFERENCES `BDA`.`Departamento` (`nombre_depto`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `dni` FOREIGN KEY (`dni`) REFERENCES `BDA`.`Trabajador` (`dni`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION, CONSTRAINT `anho_contable` FOREIGN KEY (`anho_contable`) REFERENCES `BDA`.`Capitulo_Contable` (`anho_contable`) [...]

MySQL said: Documentation

#1022 - Can't write; duplicate key in table 'ug'
```

I export the result of the diagram from Mysql Workbench to a SQL file, and this file is what I'm trying to upload.

This is the file. I can not find the duplicate key.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `BDA` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `BDA` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BDA`.`Departamento`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`Departamento` (
  `nombre_depto` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  `area_depto` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nombre_depto`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BDA`.`Trabajador`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`Trabajador` (
  `dni` INT NOT NULL,
  `direccion` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_nacimiento` DATE NOT NULL,
  `fecha_contrato` DATE NOT NULL,
  `titulacion` VARCHAR(140) NULL,
  `nombre_depto` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`dni`),
  INDEX `nombre_depto_idx` (`nombre_depto` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `nombre_depto`
    FOREIGN KEY (`nombre_depto`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`Departamento` (`nombre_depto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BDA`.`Capitulo_Contable`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`Capitulo_Contable` (
  `anho_contable` INT NOT NULL,
  `numero_ug` INT NOT NULL,
  `debe` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `haber` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`anho_contable`),
  INDEX `numero_ug_idx` (`numero_ug` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `numero_ug`
    FOREIGN KEY (`numero_ug`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`UG` (`numero_ug`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BDA`.`UG`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`UG` (
  `numero_ug` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `segunda_firma_autorizada` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_creacion` DATE NOT NULL,
  `nombre_depto` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  `dni` INT NOT NULL,
  `anho_contable` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`numero_ug`),
  INDEX `nombre_depto_idx` (`nombre_depto` ASC),
  INDEX `dni_idx` (`dni` ASC),
  INDEX `anho_contable_idx` (`anho_contable` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `nombre_depto`
    FOREIGN KEY (`nombre_depto`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`Departamento` (`nombre_depto`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `dni`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dni`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`Trabajador` (`dni`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `anho_contable`
    FOREIGN KEY (`anho_contable`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`Capitulo_Contable` (`anho_contable`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BDA`.`Cliente`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`Cliente` (
  `cif_cliente` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre_cliente` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cif_cliente`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BDA`.`Ingreso`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`Ingreso` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `concepto` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `importe` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `cif_cliente` INT NOT NULL,
  `numero_ug` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `cif_cliente_idx` (`cif_cliente` ASC),
  INDEX `numero_ug_idx` (`numero_ug` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `cif_cliente`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cif_cliente`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`Cliente` (`cif_cliente`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `numero_ug`
    FOREIGN KEY (`numero_ug`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`UG` (`numero_ug`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BDA`.`Proveedor`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`Proveedor` (
  `cif_proveedor` INT NOT NULL,
  `nombre_proveedor` VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cif_proveedor`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `BDA`.`Gasto`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `BDA`.`Gasto` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `concepto` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `importe` DOUBLE NOT NULL,
  `fecha` DATE NOT NULL,
  `factura` INT NOT NULL,
  `cif_proveedor` INT NOT NULL,
  `numero_ug` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `cif_proveedor_idx` (`cif_proveedor` ASC),
  INDEX `numero_ug_idx` (`numero_ug` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `cif_proveedor`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cif_proveedor`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`Proveedor` (`cif_proveedor`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `numero_ug`
    FOREIGN KEY (`numero_ug`)
    REFERENCES `BDA`.`UG` (`numero_ug`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Thanks for your advices.

Comment: Have you tried to create the table `BDA`.`Capitulo_Contable` after the table `BDA`.`UG` in your script?  It is creating a foreign key on the table `BDA`.`UG` which has not yet been created.

Comment: Actually I think your problem is a duplicate constraint name nombre_depto.  See this answer for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15014592/mysql-error-1022-when-creating-table

Comment: Ok, ok! I think that is the contraint name. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As [Kevin Horgan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118871/kevin-horgan) said, the problem was foreign keys, which can not be repeated.

Thank you.