# How can i see index present in mysql

Tags: mysql

1. I have created a index on my table this way

   ```
   CREATE UNIQUE INDEX  viid_in_item_topping  ON item_topping (item_id)
   ```
2. I am checking indexes on that  table this way

   ```
   SHOW INDEXES FROM item_topping;
   ```

It displayed output as

```
viid_in_item_topping
```

How can i see this particualr index ??

(Means on what field  i created index)

I have tried using show viid_in_item_topping , desc viid_in_item_topping but nothing worked .

Could you please let me know how to see the index by its name ??

This question is not the same as posted in the link , how can i see the index by its name

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to see indexes for a database or table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table)

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE item_topping` will dump the table's current state, with indexes.

Comment: How The output of `SHOW INDEXES FROM item_topping` should display lots more information than just the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by either SHOW CREATE TABLE or looking in INFORMATION_SCEHMA:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE item_topping;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS WHERE TABLE_NAME='item_topping'
```

The former is usually easier to read.