# Oracle user_indexes translation to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, migration

I have Oracle query:

```
SELECT index_name, table_name FROM user_indexes;
```

Since `user_indexes` is Oracle-specific view, how can I translate it to MySQL? This is my try:

```
DECLARE currrentDB      VARCHAR(64);
SELECT DATABASE() INTO currrentDB;
SELECT  INDEX_NAME, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.statistics s
        WHERE UPPER(s.TABLE_SCHEMA) = UPPER(currrentDB);
```

Are these two SQL statements are equivalent?

Comment: see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle user_indexes view contains informations about the indexes stored in the schema of the currently connected user.

As in  Mysql SCHEMA=DB, the select proposed by you can be considered equivalent to the select from Oracle's user_indexes view.
Regards
Giova