# Mysql using IN to search for entry which contains every IN clausle word

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have this Mysql Query:

```
SELECT page_id FROM page
WHERE page_title IN ('paul', 'mccartney')
```

My target is to get the article which includes this two words (in this example possible more words). I have a article where `page_title` contains `'paul mccartney'`. The problem he's only searching for rows which containing on of the words, and it returns me the entry with only `'paul'` as the `page_title`. I want, that the server returns the row where the `page_title` contains every of my words which are in the in clausle.

Comment: *"I have a article where page_title contains 'paul mccartney'"* and you're using `IN()`? that doesn't make any sense and your question is unclear. You need to show us what your db schema looks like.

Comment: it looks like this http://prntscr.com/9smpoe

Comment: `IN()` is an array search of a column. You want `WHERE page_title = "paul mccartney"`

Comment: yes it makes no sense and i don't know how i can solve the problem fast, because i know i can use the LIKE parameter for every word but it's very slow if there are mor than 3 words.

Comment: how can it be slow? if your db's not indexed, then that will slow it down. MySQL should be able to handle thousands of records with no problem. Your query's failing because those contain underscores. another issue

Comment: did you know how i can find out if my db's are indexed?

Comment: `LIKE '%mcartney%'` I can't see how that would be slow. But if your db's setup to be case-sensitive, that could be another issue.

Comment: how to see if indexed https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html `SHOW INDEX FROM [tablename]` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5213364/

Comment: made a mistake, I missed a "c" `LIKE '%mccartney%'` but am sure you knew that ;-)

Comment: haha yes saw it. And i used the show index command and it returns me that http://prntscr.com/9smxa8 is it good?

Comment: Do an EXPLAIN with the query to see which index is uses.

Comment: what did u mean with explain?

Answer (score 1):

You could always use `union`

```
SELECT page_id FROM page
WHERE page_title Like '%paul%'
UNION 
SELECT page_id FROM page
WHERE page_title Like '%mccartney%'
```