# Select indexes for all tables

Tags: mysql

How can I get all indexes for all tables on my DB?
Something like `show index`, but such as I could execute for all tables on a given DB and, more important, that I could use as a subquery.

Please notice that I'm not interested on the primary key, but on another index.

**Edit:**
So the solution that I was looking for is (based on aarbor's answer):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME,
    INDEX_NAME,
    COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = schema() and index_name <> 'PRIMARY';
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    TABLE_NAME,
    INDEX_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'your_schema';
```

Taken from: [This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I didn't realize this table had the column names as well.