# Mssql check if index is generated or not

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

In Oracle `[ALL_INDEXES]` contains a column named `[GENERATED]` which specifies whether or not that index is created by system.

However, I can not find same method for sql server and postgres.

Comment: Check this out [indexed in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table)

Comment: There is no such property for Postgres. You can't distinguish the system generated names from the user supplied names.

Comment: In case of postgresql, index is created by system generally start from **pg_** but I am not sure.