# Unknown table 'table_name' in information_schema

Tags: mysql, information-schema, database-indexes

I want to `show index` from each table that has `table_schema='foo'` (database name).

```
mysql> show index from table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='foo';
ERROR 1109 (42S02): Unknown table 'table_name' in information_schema
```

From the error, I see that the query treats `'table_name'` as a table in `information_schema`.  How do I rewrite the query to treat `'table_name'` as a column in `information_schema.tables`?

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table

Comment: Why would you ever think that `from table_name from` would be valid syntax? It's not even close to anything acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're approaching this wrong, and you're making up syntax that doesn't exist.

I suggest the way you want to get the indexes is by reading the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS` table, not the `TABLES` table.

The following query has the same columns as `SHOW INDEXES`:

```
SELECT table_name AS `Table`, Non_unique, index_name AS Key_name,
  Seq_in_index, Column_name, Collation, Cardinality, Sub_part,
  Packed, Nullable, Index_type, Comment, Index_comment 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.STATISTICS 
WHERE table_schema = 'foo';
```

You might think there should be an I_S table called "INDEXES" but in fact the system table for index objects is named "STATISTICS". Go figure.

Comment: This does give my desired result.  But is there a way to programmatically get all the tables instead of typing them all out?  Also, I realize your query is the better approach, but is there syntax for what I was originally trying to do?  Basically execute a query on each item of a list returned by another query.

Comment: No, there is no syntax for `SHOW INDEXES` to have it take the result of another query as the list of tables. You'd have to run the query to get the list of tables, and as a second step, build a dynamic SQL query with a `SHOW INDEXES ...` statement.