# How to get the primary key "column name" of a specific table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Our system creates a log of every table that was updated or inserted with new content, it saves the table name, the ID value of the updated row or the last id inserted and the timestamp of the event.

This is useful because we can check what is the latest table updated and refresh the information being displayed to the user as soon as a change occurs, but we don't have the column name of the ID saved on the log.

The problem is that we are programming case by case in php.

```
if($tableName == 'Clients'){ $idname = 'CID'; }
```

is there a way to just ask MySQL: give me the primary key column name of a specific table, something like:

```
SHOW COLUMN_NAME FROM CLEINTS WHERE KEY_NAME = 'PRIMARY KEY';
```

I remember I had used a query like this in the past, but I can't remember what it was, I have found some solutions for SQL but don't seem to work in MySQL or are way too complicated (using `information_schema`), the query that I am looking for is very simple, almost like the example I just gave.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table

Comment: Close: `SHOW INDEX FROM CLIENTS WHERE KEY_NAME = 'PRIMARY';`

Comment: Not bad, SHOW INDEX FROM... is good, almost there! That returns all the indexes, including key_Name 'primary' an the column name, but it returns too much information, I just want the primary key name. Thanks!

Comment: try this: `SHOW KEYS FROM CLEINTS WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: @Nick, if you can add that as a response, I might take it as a good answer, it is very very close and definitely useful

Comment: @JigarShah this is all great, seriously add them as answers, I am looking something like: SHOW KEYS.column_name FROM CLIENTS WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY', maybe it is not possible, please add your answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the details from `information_schema` database. Use the following query:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Your_table_name' 
  AND CONSTRAINT_NAME = 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: This is very good! It is exactly the result that I wanted, maybe information_schema was required after all, Thanks!

Comment: Up-vote the question if you think it might be useful for other users. Thanks!

Comment: @multimediaxp Somehow I am getting three times the same column name (PK) for a particular table in my case. I have added a DISTINCT clause to this solution. Please accept the edit :)

Comment: Madhur Bhaiya HOW??? We talking about MYSQL. ONLY one PRIMARY key per table and all keys MUST have unique names.

Answer (score 2):

You can get `KEYS` by using

```
SHOW KEYS FROM CLEINTS WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

another alternative with SHOW to get `INDEXES` as @nick mentioned in comment

```
SHOW INDEXES FROM CLEINTS WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY'
```

syntax:

```
SHOW [EXTENDED] {INDEX | INDEXES | KEYS}
    {FROM | IN} tbl_name
    [{FROM | IN} db_name]
    [WHERE expr]
```

[documentation link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-index.html) for more details.

Comment: Up-vote the question if you think is useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hello @multimediaxp i think this may help you.

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME`
FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE (`TABLE_SCHEMA` = 'yourDBName')
  AND (`TABLE_NAME` = 'Clients')
  AND (`COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI');
```

For more detail please see given link:
http://mysql-0v34c10ck.blogspot.com/2011/05/better-way-to-get-primary-key-columns.html

Comment: I don't want to use information_schema, it is more in the form of: SHOW KEYS FROM CLEINTS WHERE Key_name = 'PRIMARY' as previous comments have added.

Comment: BTW it looks like a good option but it returns an empty result. :(

Comment: @multimediaxp it works for me. I believe you have a typo in your Clients tablename

Comment: i checked and it is all written properly, is `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI' correct? I tried `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRIMARY and it is the same, returns empty'