# What is Mysql's SHOW INDEX alternative in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for alternative of MYSQL's 'Show Index' in SQL Server. Can anybody please help?

show index dbname.tablename;

Comment: You can probe sys.indexes view.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table-in-mysql

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765867/list-of-all-index-index-columns-in-sql-server-db

Answer (score 0):

you can use sp_helpindex to get indexes on table

```
EXEC sp_helpindex 'table_name';
```

using @marc_s's query [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/765892/1118978) you can create view

```
create view show_indexes as
SELECT 
     TableName = t.name,
     IndexName = ind.name,
     IndexId = ind.index_id,
     ColumnId = ic.index_column_id,
     ColumnName = col.name,
     ind.*,
     ic.*,
     col.* 
FROM 
     sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE 
     ind.is_primary_key = 0 
     AND ind.is_unique = 0 
     AND ind.is_unique_constraint = 0 
     AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0 
ORDER BY 
     t.name, ind.name, ind.index_id, ic.index_column_id;
```

then you can use it with select

```
select * from show_indexes where table_name = ...
```

Comment: Or use the system proc:  `EXEC sp_helpindex 'table_name';`.