# Export only the indexes from mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database. For which I need to retrieve only the indexes present in my entire database, Is there any way I could get it? OR get a 
 `CREATE` indexes script which will help me do so.
I just don't want to SELECT them, rather I would like to get a script which when executed on similar database - the indexes will be added

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table-in-mysql ?

Comment: You can use the query from the below post. https://stackoverflow.com/a/5213364/10342514

Comment: I just don't want to `SELECT`  them, rather I would like to get a script which when  executed on similar database - the indexes will be added

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see indexes for a database or table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table-in-mysql)

Comment: You probably need a stored procedure to run through the output of `SHOW INDEX` from each table and build a dynamic SQL query to recreate them all.