# How to get all the tables with auto increment primary key in mysql?

Tags: mysql

There are huge tables in my mysql database, I want to get all the tables with auto increment columns and the columns' names. Could anyone teach me how to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to see indexes for a database or table in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5213339/how-to-see-indexes-for-a-database-or-table-in-mysql)

Comment: @RaymondNijland  sorry, I don't think so. I am considering to get the information from information_schema.Columns.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get that information from the [`COLUMNS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/columns-table.html) table in the [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html) schema.

E.g.

```
select TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME from COLUMNS where `COLUMN_KEY` = 'PRI' and EXTRA like '%auto_increment%'
```

Comment: No be aware you can define a PRIMARY KEY without defining a AUTO_INCREMENT.. -> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbADd4roKNmxXca4C2i5QY/0

Comment: Did you test that?  It is incorrect after some test on mysql 8.

Comment: Well in that table you would not have an auto increment on column a. Try to do two inserts without defining the column a.

Comment: That was mean as a "example" case.. @LazerBass , [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jbADd4roKNmxXca4C2i5QY/0) would make more sense..

Comment: using `EXTRA LIKE '%auto_increment%'` instead might be a bit better as extra can have multiple values from how the manual explains the extra coiumn..

Comment: Thanks! I adjusted it.